# How to resize webview correctly in landscape mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, resize, landscape

I add a navigationbar, a webview and a toolbar(from top to bottom) as subviews of my viewcontroller's view. I want the navigationbar and toolbar's height shrink a little in landscape orientation so I use autoresizingmask to make the height flexible. (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight will make navigationbar and toolbar's height shrink from 44 to around 30):

```
webNavBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
webToolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Now I found that when I rotate the device to landscape mode, there will be two blank white bars on the top and bottom of the webview(each blank bar's height is 44-30). Navigationbar and toolbar appear to be in the correct position. Is there any way to resize the webview and fill the gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the Autoresizing margins are set correctly for the webview? could always do:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
   webView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

No idea if that will work but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the webview is not a full screen view. Anyway, you give me an idea that I may reset its frame to get a correct size.

Comment: Make sure you also call through to the `super` method in case you are doing anything in the super class.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link.
[`UIWebView` not re-sizing after changing orientation to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061327/uiwebview-not-resizing-after-changing-orientation-to-landscape)

This worked for me: -
Add the following code to the controller which has the webView: -

```
 (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration  
 {
     [self.myWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
 }
```

Comment: Make sure you also call through to the `super` method in case you are doing anything in the super class.